# Android ListView: mouseover action

Tags: android

I am new to Android application Development.

How can I identify the mouseover action for a list box? On mouse over of a particular cell I want to highlight that cell or change the background color.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a concept of MouseOver in Android, at least one that I know of - user interaction is done through hardware/virtual keyboard and touchscreen.

ListView automatically highlights the current selection, so when you use the up and down DPad keys, you may get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but my queries kept returning to this original post so I wanted to share it here.

For what it is worth, implementing the state_hovered in your selector will NOT work for list views on mouse over events.

You can achieve this event using custom array adapter.
*This assumes you know how to create your own selector and ArrayAdapter. If not, you can find those in other Stack Overflow posts.

1. Create your own array adapter.
2. Implement View.OnHoverListener in the adapter
3. Override the 'onHover'method:

`@Override
    public boolean onHover(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        int ev = arg1.getActionMasked();
        switch (ev) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
            arg0.setHovered(true);
            arg0.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
            arg0.setHovered(false);
            arg0.setSelected(false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }`