# how to know the coordinates of image when touch 

Tags: android

How to get image coordinates at mouse hover position.

Please let me know

Thank you

Comment: ... You have a *mouse* attached to your Android device!? :) I've seen this [other post here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371495/android-listview-mouseover-action) stating that Android doesn't have that concept. Can't say whether this is 100% accurate, though, but it would make sense...

Comment: Do you mean the current position of a touch event? Like if you touch the screen, get that position?

Comment: ha yes, i set image as background i need to get current position of touch.... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set an onTouchListener for the image, and in the onTouch event, you can pull the x,y coordinates out of the MotionEvent. getX and getY will get you the x and y coordinates in relation to the image, and getRawX and getRawY will get the x,y coordinates of the screen.

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
   System.out.println("X: "+arg1.getX());
   System.out.println("Y: "+arg1.getY());
   System.out.println("Raw X: "+arg1.getRawX());
   System.out.println("Raw Y: "+arg1.getRawY());
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from the "android-porting" mailing list (end of August 2010):

> *Android currently doesn't support mouse input, so has no concept of mouse hover.*

Answer (score 0):

As stakx said, Android doesn't support the mouse. However, if you are referring to the image that currently has focus, try this:

```
Image focusedImg = getViewById(R.id.YourMainLayout).findFocus();

int[] relativeToParentPixels = { focusedImg.getLeft(), focusedImg.getTop(), 
                                 focusedImg.getRight(), focusedImg.getBottom() };
```

Now you'll have the boundary positions of the image in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnHoverListener.html

Available from api 14.